# Debezium postgres ERROR: parameter "include-unchanged-toast" was deprecated

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I am doing a load test on Debezium postgres connector at the moment to know if it can support very massive amounts (in terms of billions) of changes logs in Aurora Postgres.
When I insert 1 million records to the postgres table, Debezium Postgres connector failed with following error messages:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: An exception ocurred in the change event producer. This connector will be stopped.
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.throwProducerFailureIfPresent(ChangeEventQueue.java:170)
    at io.debezium.connector.base.ChangeEventQueue.poll(ChangeEventQueue.java:151)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnectorTask.poll(PostgresConnectorTask.java:188)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.poll(WorkerSourceTask.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask.execute(WorkerSourceTask.java:226)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: parameter "include-unchanged-toast" was deprecated
  Where: slot "wal2json_dbz5", output plugin "wal2json", in the startup callback

    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2440)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processCopyResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1116)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.readFromCopy(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1035)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.CopyDualImpl.readFromCopy(CopyDualImpl.java:41)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.receiveNextData(V3PGReplicationStream.java:155)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readInternal(V3PGReplicationStream.java:124)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.replication.V3PGReplicationStream.readPending(V3PGReplicationStream.java:78)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.connection.PostgresReplicationConnection$1.readPending(PostgresReplicationConnection.java:401)
    at io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.execute(PostgresStreamingChangeEventSource.java:94)
    at io.debezium.pipeline.ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.lambda$start$0(ChangeEventSourceCoordinator.java:91)
```

It seems connector does not support `include-unchanged-toast` anymore. Is there any workaround to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either get Debrezium fixed or you can use an old version of wal2json from before [the option was removed](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json/commit/66d836d209f71f2337ea622ae63669d759e30926).

The GIT snapshot of wal2json from just before the option was removed is [here](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json/archive/d4c0e814696695bbf853c48b38b7479e0f83f6c7.zip).

Be warned, though, that the option was removed [for a good reason](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json/issues/74).

Comment: This should no longer be a problem with Debezium 0.10.0.Final.  The user should simply update to a minimum of that release and should be fine.

Comment: We are using Debezium 0.10.0, but still have this issue @Naros

Comment: Based on the stack trace, that looks like its probably 0.10.0.CR2 rather than 0.10.0.Final.  But either way, the fix for this was added prior to that so technically that shouldn't matter.  If you're still experiencing an issue then I'd open an issue with all the pertinent details and we can review it.

Comment: @raja Did the issue get resolved or is there a link to any ticket following this issue?